# Is it possible to create a function in PostgreSQL that takes a column name as input?

Tags: database, function, postgresql, plpgsql

I have two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1_lang
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  lang1 character varying,
  lang2 character varying,
  ...
)

CREATE TABLE table2_lang
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  table1_id NOT NULL,
  lang1 character varying,
  lang2 character varying,
  ...
)
```

Each of the lang columns contains a name in different languages.
I want to create a function that returns the selected lang from table1_lang if it exist. 
If the name does not exist in table1_lang then the function should return the name from table2_lang.

So far I have solved my problem with this function in plpgsql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_name(integer, text)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    in_id ALIAS FOR $1;
    lang ALIAS FOR $2;
    table1_name varchar;
    table2_name varchar;
BEGIN
    IF lang IS NOT NULL AND lang = 'lang1' THEN
        SELECT a.lang1 INTO table1_name
            FROM table1_lang a
            WHERE a.id = in_id;

            IF table1_name IS NOT NULL AND length(table1_name) > 0 THEN
            RETURN table1_name;
        ELSE
            SELECT a.lang1 INTO table2_name
            FROM table2_lang a
            WHERE a.table1_id = in_id;

            IF table2_name IS NOT NULL AND length(table2_name) > 0 THEN
                RETURN table2_name;
            END IF;
        END IF; 
    END IF;

    IF lang IS NOT NULL AND lang = 'lang2' THEN
        SELECT a.lang2 INTO table1_name
            FROM table1_lang a
            WHERE a.id = in_id;

            IF table1_name IS NOT NULL AND length(table1_name) > 0 THEN
            RETURN table1_name;
        ELSE
            SELECT a.lang2 INTO table2_name
            FROM table2_lang a
            WHERE a.table1_id = in_id;

            IF table2_name IS NOT NULL AND length(table2_name) > 0 THEN
                RETURN table2_name;
            END IF;
        END IF;             
    END IF;

    ...

    IF table2_name IS NULL OR length(table2_name) = 0 THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION get_name(integer, text) OWNER TO postgres;
```

But I would like to know if is it possible to create a function in plpgsql or other languages available in PostgreSQL that takes a column as input parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible in a plpgsql function. But if identifiers (including column names) are parametrized you have to build dynamic SQL and execute it with `EXECUTE`. Read about that in [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). Pay attention not to allow SQL injection by doing that. Make use of [`quote_ident()` or `format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html).

I have written a couple of similar answers with links and explanation. Try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8146245/939860) for a start or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044006/spatial-data-sql-reprojection-function-issues/8044033#8044033).